# How to reference lodash 3.10.1 from node_modules to html file?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I noticed that lodash@3.10.1 structure has changed to a modular format, how can I reference lodash from node_modules to my html page? We are not allowed to use bower, so npm is the only option.

Thanks!

Comment: Why con't you use just a simple relative path like `/node_modules/etc..` assuming that your HTML is in the root.

Comment: the problem is which file should i reference to? if you install the current lodash with npm, the file structure will be different than before. I couldn't find "lodash.js" in the node_modules/lodash/ directory

Comment: I think you have to import `index.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [bower](http://bower.io/), the package manager for the "front end". For example type in your CLI assuming you are project root directory:

```
npm install -g bower
bower install lodash
```

In your `index.html` include lodash.js assuming it is your project root directory as well:

```
<script src="bower_components/lodash/lodash.js"></script>
```